# Which Domain to use for the Google Cloud Console Organization Setup if Working with Different Domains

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform, microsoft-office-365, mx-record, godaddy

I have some questions about setting up the GCC Organization please.

A new Google Cloud Console account was created when setting up this domain in the Organization section of an existing GCC account created by Merchant Center.

https://prnt.sc/TEgoj0JT0jPg
GMC account - Admin@KingBrownEnterprises.com

https://prnt.sc/bbzyHTR-Qben
Domain account - kingbrownenterprises.com

1. Can the Domain account be merged with the Merchant Center version? The Organization set up in the MC version doesn't recognize the new Domain and doesn't merge them when accounts are switched from Admin@KingBrownEnterprises.com https://prnt.sc/BAXseSzSS2HN.

GoDaddy's Microsoft365 account was removed from the domain when the DNS record was updated in kingbrownenterprises.com within the GoDaddy dashboard.

2. How can Microsoft365 be activated while using Google Cloud Console? ChatGPT gave some instructions but not enough to complete the task.

[ChapGPT said:
As of my last knowledge update in January 2023, the exact navigation within the Google Cloud Console may have changed. However, I can provide general guidance on where you might find domain management settings within the Google Cloud Console. Please note that interfaces and navigation may be updated, so the steps might vary:

1. **Log in to Google Cloud Console:**
   Visit the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and log in to your Google Cloud account.
2. **Navigate to the Networking section:**
   In the left-hand navigation pane, look for a section related to networking or infrastructure. This might be labeled as "Network Services" or something similar.
3. **Find the Domain Registration or Cloud DNS:**
   Within the networking section, you should find a category related to Domain Registration or Cloud DNS. Click on it.
4. **Locate your domain:**
   You should see a list of your registered domains or DNS configurations. Look for the specific domain you want to manage.
5. **Access DNS settings:**

**Click on the domain you want to manage, and you should find settings related to DNS records. This is where you can update your DNS records to point to the desired email service, such as GoDaddy Office 365.**

Remember that Google Cloud's interface may be updated, so the labels and locations might vary. If you have trouble finding the specific settings, consider checking the Google Cloud documentation or reaching out to Google Cloud support for assistance.]

This process isn't available in the Domain GCC because a project isn't setup https://prnt.sc/MmoqECq2Q1UB and in the Merchant Center GCC is more accessible but have to activate a paid API https://prnt.sc/p6UiraE721Um and https://prnt.sc/YFd3E4qKQYOo. The Domain GCC setup was not started to not create anything not needed.

This last thing is my biggest concern regarding setting up the Organization account. The fact projects need to be created to access DNS configurations has me think the wrong domain was used in the Organization setup. The Merchant Center GCC is connected to my website https://MadeInTheAmericas.com that doesn't have an email account but the Organization setup in MC-GCC instructed to use a "Business" domain not a website domain. Kingbrownenterprises.com is a business domain and was used for it's email accounts but now think madeintheamericas.com should have been used to link with MC-GCC.

3. Should I delete the kingbrownenterprises.com Work Space and create a new one using madeintheamericas.com? I could setup email accounts for madeintheamericas if needed and nothing in kingbrownenterprises GCC was setup yet.

Hope this wasn't confusing and look forward to hearing from you.